# How to search for, and filter, based on set of character strings across multiple columns using R

Tags: r

I have a series of numeric/character codes that I need to search across multiple columns in R and then filter/subset the data when there is at least one match. I have read a number of similar stack overflow queries, but none seem to match my issue.

I have tried the below code, but my challenge is that this only identifies matches when it begins with the code of interest. However, there are instances in the data where the code will appear in the middle, or at the end, of the sequence of numbers/characters in the cell. I also need to capture those instances, not just when it begins with the code of interest.

```
codes <- c("1HY85","1HZ85","1GT85","1GR85", "1OA85","1PC85","1OJ85","1OK85","1NK85","1NP85")
sub_data <- og_data %>%
filter_at(.vars = vars(Code_1:Code_10),
              .vars_predicate = any_vars(str_detect(. , paste0("(", paste(codes, collapse = "|"), ")"))))
```

This is an example of what the data looks like:

```
structure(list(unique_record_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10), Code_1 = c("1SC27JA", "1PC85LAXXJ", "1PC85LAXXK", "1PC85LAXXK", 
"1PC85LAXXJ", "1PC85LAXXK", "1PC85LAXXK", "XXJ1NK85YY", "1PC85LAXXJ", 
"1PC85LAXXJ"), Code_2 = c("NA", "1PG80LD", "1PZ21HQBR1OA85", 
"1PC85LAXXK", "1SY80LA", "1PC85LAXXK", "1PG87LA", "1OT53HATS", 
"1PC85LAXXJ", "1JQ55GRLG"), Code_3 = c("NA", "1PG50LABJ", "NA", 
"NA", "1PG80LA", "1PZ21HQBR", "1PG50LABJ", "1PZ21HPD4", "1PE76LA", 
"NA"), Code_4 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1PG51NK850LABJ", "1IS55GRLF", 
"1IS55GRLF", NA, "1PG50LABJ", "NA"), Code_5 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1PG50LABJ", "NA"), Code_6 = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "2PC71LA", "NA"), Code_7 = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "2PC71LA", "NA"), Code_8 = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1IS53GRLF", "NA"), 
    Code_9 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA"), Code_10 = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Perhaps: `df1 %>% filter(if_any(Code_1:Code_10, ~str_detect(., paste(codes, collapse = "|"))))`.

Comment: No, unfortunately that produces the same result as my original code (which is to say, it filters those that start with the codes of interest, but none of the instances where the code is in the middle or at the end of the cell are filtered in).

Comment: Mind to create some example data that gives a wrong output with your code and additionally your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using `data.table`. What is your expected output in your example?

Below I use `%ilike%` and combine all the various codes above into one expression to match across each cell in the selected column of interests. This returns a data.table of TRUEs if there's a match and FALSE otherwise. Then I use `apply` combined with `any` to return TRUE if any row has a TRUE in it. I then subset to only include rows that are TRUE to get the ids and left join the ids table with the original dataset.

```
library(data.table)

# orig == og_data
# codes == codes

orig = as.data.table(orig)
cols = names(orig)[(names(orig) %like% "Code")]

# Find matches across all relevant columns
bool_orig = copy(orig)
bool_orig[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {x %ilike% paste0(codes,collapse = "|")}), .SDcols = cols]

# Pull ids that have at least 1 TRUE value
ids = bool_orig[, match := apply(.SD, 1, any), .SDcols = cols][(match), .(unique_record_id)]

orig[ids, on = "unique_record_id"]

#    unique_record_id     Code_1         Code_2    Code_3         Code_4    Code_5  Code_6  Code_7    Code_8 Code_9 Code_10
# 1:                2 1PC85LAXXJ        1PG80LD 1PG50LABJ             NA        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 2:                3 1PC85LAXXK 1PZ21HQBR1OA85        NA             NA        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 3:                4 1PC85LAXXK     1PC85LAXXK        NA             NA        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 4:                5 1PC85LAXXJ        1SY80LA   1PG80LA 1PG51NK850LABJ        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 5:                6 1PC85LAXXK     1PC85LAXXK 1PZ21HQBR      1IS55GRLF        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 6:                7 1PC85LAXXK        1PG87LA 1PG50LABJ      1IS55GRLF        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 7:                8 XXJ1NK85YY      1OT53HATS 1PZ21HPD4           <NA>        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 8:                9 1PC85LAXXJ     1PC85LAXXJ   1PE76LA      1PG50LABJ 1PG50LABJ 2PC71LA 2PC71LA 1IS53GRLF     NA      NA
# 9:               10 1PC85LAXXJ      1JQ55GRLG        NA             NA        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
```

To show that it matches any part of the string:

```
# run the above using "LAB" as the pattern
codes = c("LAB")

#    unique_record_id     Code_1     Code_2    Code_3         Code_4    Code_5  Code_6  Code_7    Code_8 Code_9 Code_10
# 1:                2 1PC85LAXXJ    1PG80LD 1PG50LABJ             NA        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 2:                5 1PC85LAXXJ    1SY80LA   1PG80LA 1PG51NK850LABJ        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 3:                7 1PC85LAXXK    1PG87LA 1PG50LABJ      1IS55GRLF        NA      NA      NA        NA     NA      NA
# 4:                9 1PC85LAXXJ 1PC85LAXXJ   1PE76LA      1PG50LABJ 1PG50LABJ 2PC71LA 2PC71LA 1IS53GRLF     NA      NA
```